# How to kill all threads when WPF app was closed

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF app. I am starting some threads. When I close the app it is still running in the background (I am seeing from Task Manager) because Threads are still running.  I want to kill all threads when the app was closed. Here is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Thread thread;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(abc));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void abc(object obj)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

In this case, when I click the button and close the app, it will still be running in the background for 10 seconds. How can I kill all threads on the closing app?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Why do you explicitly create threads instead of using the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) to create tasks which is the recommended way to write multithreaded and parallel code since .NET Framework 4.0? This will run your delegates on background threads by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A thread can either be a foreground or a background thread. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netcore-3.1):

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. **Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.**

A thread created via the constructor of the `Thread` class is a foreground thread by default. Consequently, you can make a thread a background thread to terminate it when your application closes by setting the `IsBackground` property to `true`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(abc));
   thread.IsBackground = true;
   thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: In this case, It is fixed when I use thread.IsBackground = true; but a lot of people wrote code on the project. Sometimes I am seeing this problem but it is not reproducible. I want to close all threads when Window of WPF was closed

Comment: private void MainWindow_Closed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }

Comment: This solves issue but I am not sure it is correct way

Comment: Regarding Kill, see this related question. If you are working on a project with others and you can observe that sometimes there are threads pending you should not blindly kill them when the application shuts down. This could lead to serious issues. Rather debug the application to find out who started the threads and shut them down appropriately. By killing threads at application shutdown, you solve the consequence, not the actual issue.

Comment: @DIlshodK you should probably work out a shutdown procedure/strategy, to which all participants in the project should abide. It seems that currently the project is governed by anarchy.